# Keep dirty form values on reinitialize in final-form

Tags: javascript, final-form

Is there a way to keep dirty values on reinitialize of final-form (`keepDirtyOnReinitialize` flag from redux-form analogue)?

In my case I have a big form and I want to be able to edit part of it's data in a subform without losing changes in a parent form.

Comment: You will need to save values to local storage. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: I don't hide a parent form so I don't have to save values anywhere. The problem is that then i use final-form's initialize method with new data it erases all the previous state (with changes and dirty values)